# postgresql - paginate correctly ordering by non-distinct values?

Tags: postgresql

How can I properly page by ordering on a column that could possibly have repeated values? I have a table called `posts`, which has a column that holds the number of likes of a certain post, called `num_likes`, and I want to order by `num_likes DESC`. But, the image below shows a problem that I run into - the new row inserted between the two pages causes repeated data to be fetched.

[This link here](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset) explains the problem, and gives the solution of *keyset pagination*, but from what I've seen, that only works if the column that the rows are being sorted on are **distinct / unique**. How would I do this if that is not the case?

[image: new row problem pagination]

Comment: Why is fetching repeated data a problem? It does after all reflect the reality -- once the new row is inserted "row 10" _is_ on the second page.

Comment: @mustaccio Because there are repeated rows, **row 10 is repeated**. For all steps, `limit = 10`. For step 1, `offset = 0`, so I fetch rows 1-10. At step 3, `offset = 10`, but since the new row is inserted, it repeatedly fetches **row 10**.

Comment: @MichaelHsu - However, if the user went back to the first page of data, they'd see  "new row" and rows 1-9 - row 10 would no longer show up there. This may be explicitly stated in your requirements as "not acceptable"; however, if nothing explicit is said about is, it's worth asking. For some uses, seeing new rows at all would be considered an issue; for others, no one might care, and would know that seeing rows twice would just mean that new rows had shown up in data that had already been seen.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the simplest solution is to sort on *multiple* columns (the one(s) you need for your basic sort, plus another column (or set of columns) that would make the effective "key" of your query unique).

This is more difficult (but may not be impossible) if your table(s) don't have a primary or unique key; you'd have to establish that there *is* a set of columns that could uniquely identify the rows you're presenting.